# Check if logged in user is member of AD group with ECMA script SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

There is active directory group added to SharePoint group. How would we can check that the logged in user is member of that active directory group using ECMA script?

Answer (score 2):

Workaround

1. Create a hidden list
2. Break inheritance of the list
3. Give read permission only to the SharePoint group in question
4. Try reading from the list using JSOM
5. If read succeeds then the current user is part of the AD group, else not

Note - The above solution is not tested

Comment: Thanks. Was looking for a way to add validation on a people picker for a specific AD group.

Answer (score 1):

You can't out of the box.

If you still need to do this, then look into expanding the rest api, to allow this. But a caveat on this, is this will only be possible on premises.

Reference material: http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2014/04/17/Extending-SharePoint-2013-REST-APIs.aspx